# C# Delegate,Action,Func ?? How to write it to make shorter code

Tags: c#, lambda, uwp, delegates, action

I want to know a good idea to Rewrite my class with Lambda + delegate + Func/Action.

in my code, there is lot of Lock wrapper ( to save a Sqlite model ).

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
....
    private SemaphoreSlim AsyncLock = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
....
    private async Task LockWork1(SqliteModel model)
    {
        await AsyncLock.WaitAsync();
        try { await Work1(model); }
        finally { AsyncLock.Release(); }
    }
    private async Task LockWork2(SqliteModel model)
    {
        await AsyncLock.WaitAsync();
        try{await Work2(model);}
        finally{AsyncLock.Release();}
    }
    private async Task Work1(SqliteModel model){var a=model; await Task.Delay(1000);}
    private async Task Work2(SqliteModel model){var a=model; await Task.Delay(2000);}
```

I want to make a Wrapper method to use lock.
Here is my image.

```
await LockWrapper( Work1( modelInstance ) );
```

Func, Action() ? How to write it ??

Comment: I think you take `Func` and `Action` as something drastically different from delegate. They are just special types of `delegate`, they are included in the .NET Base Class Library so we don't have to define some of the most common delegate types like this `public delegate void Del(string message); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you won't be able to do it *quite* like that, but you could write:

```
await LockWrapper(() => Work1(modelInstance));
```

and write `LockWrapper` as:

```
private async Task LockWrapper(Func<Task> taskProvider)
{
    await AsyncLock.WaitAsync();
    try
    {
        await taskProvider();
    }
    finally
    { 
        AsyncLock.Release();
    }
}
```

The idea is that what you pass in is "the operation you need to perform" - you invoke that operation (`taskProvider()`) and then wait for it to complete before unlocking.

Whether that's a good idea or not is a different matter though - I don't know what your `AsyncLock` is, or whether it assumes that `WaitAsync` and `Release` will be called on the same thread. If it assumes that, this code could still be okay *if* `LockWrapper` is called in a single-thread synchronization context, but it feels a bit fragile to me.